# xercesxmldom file not found in Delphi XE4

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe4

I am migrating my Delphi 7 code to Delphi XE4.

In one of the files in Delphi 7, I found `xercesxmldom` in the uses. I found that its dcu is placed in `C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Lib`.

When I tried to compile this file in Delphi XE4 environment, I got error `xercesxmldom.dcu not found`. I searched my entire C drive but it was not there anywhere.

I thought it is deprecated now. So I commented it out as it was nowhere used in the file and project compiled successfully.

Now when I try to open dfm file by double clicking on it, I get error `No matching Dom Vendor: "XercesXML".`

When pressed OK, dfm opens fine. I don't know why am I getting this error message?

Comment: @TLama - As per your link xercesxmldom is deprecated. Its fine for me. But why I am getting error No matching Dom Vendor: "XercesXML", when I remove it?

Comment: @TLama I don't think this is a duplicate of that question

Comment: @David, you're right. This is one step further (since OP commented out the missing XML DOM provider unit). So this is really just about changing XML DOM provider. I should have read it more carefully. Sorry, nkp. Retracting my duplicate vote and removing my comments from here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because, although you have stopped referring to the `xercesxmldom` unit, your code still sets the DOM vendor to `XercesXML`. You'll need to choose a different DOM vendor. You need to locate everywhere in your program where you assign to the [`DOMVendor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.DOMVendor) property and modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is resolved. As per your answer, I found DOMVendorDesc in my dfm files which were giving me this problem. Earlier it was declared as DOMVendorDesc = 'Xerces XML', I changed it to DOMVendorDesc = 'MSXML' and everything worked fine.